# Windows 7 folder grouping control

Tags: windows-7, file-management

In Windows 7, you can in any folder select the "Group by" option to have the files grouped into neat little categories.  However, it seems somewhat limited.  For example, if I choose "Group by Name", I get the following 5 groups - `0-9`, `A-H`, `I-P`, `Q-Z`, and `Other` for anything starting with a symbol.  I have a folder containing thousands of files, and this just isn't that useful.  Is there any way to change the way that it defines its groups?  Say, one for each letter would be preferable, or maybe you could choose the number of groups or number of items per group?  Or even custom-define your own criteria for grouping?  If not, this feature is kind of pointless if it's hard-coded to just that predefined set of 5 groups.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this cannot be done:

> The option of grouping by name is an inbuilt feature of Windows 7 and cannot be modified to work with single letters (A, B, C, etc).

Source:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/is-there-a-way-to-change-how-windows-7-does-group/8d719490-605b-437f-80b4-c9262774440e

It may be worth looking into explorer alternatives (of which there are hundreds of freebies) which include the functionality you require.

Sorry and hope this helps.

Comment: Wow.  That's such a disappointment, especially since it was apparently possible back in XP.  (Been a while since I used that, but now that I think about it, yeah, I do remember being able to do this before.)  Can you offer some suggestions for alternatives?  It's kind of a drastic change to the OS for just one simple feature, and with so many options it's a bit overwhelming to choose just one...